# Trying to install Vsphere ESX 4.0 on x86

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, system-installation, vmware

I am trying to install Vsphere ESX 4.0 on my x86 machine. It is asking for Custom Drivers to install ESX.

When installed on VMware workstation it takes the current installed Ethernet interface drivers but when installed on the machine for proper set up. It is asking for the Custom Driver.

Any link where I can get the driver for ESX 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware 4.x only supports 64 bit platforms. To install on 32 bit hardware you need to install the [older version](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/?p=esxi). You should also check the [hardware compatibility guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) to see if your hardware is actually supported.

Comment: according to the list I can run ESX only in Xeon machines. Which version can I use for my Core2Duo processor, such that it can get installed easily.

Comment: Some Core2 models support 64 bit/virtualization, and some do not. You'll have to check [Intel's list](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx) and see if your specific model does.